# Форматирование текста с HTML тегами при отправке по почте

Tags: android, android-intent

При шеринге файлов передаю текстовки с интентом. В текстовках есть html-теги, которые должны преобразовывать текст, но у меня они остаются в письме в изначальном виде:
[image]

Добавляю mime тип, но все равно не форматируется. Сам интент:

```
        val sendIntent: Intent = Intent().apply {
            action = Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE
            putParcelableArrayListExtra(
                Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, ArrayList(uris)
            )
            subject?.let {
                putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject)
            }
            body?.let {
                putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body)
            }
            addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
            type = "text/html"
        }
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, getString(title)))
```

Я также попробовал такую экстру `putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_HTML_TEXT, body)`, но тогда вообще никакого текста в теле сообщения нет
А если сделать так `putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(body))`, то HTML-теги исчезают из письма, но никакого форматирования не происходит, остается просто однородный текст

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не все клиенты поддерживают HTML.
Вот работающий код для Outlook.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND );
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"recipient@example.com"});
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject Test");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "EXTRA_TEXT1 <b>123</b> <h2>big text<b2>" );
intent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity( intent );
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: И правда, в каких-то почтовых приложениях работает, а в каких-то нет. Неужели gmail не поддерживает HTML?

Comment: @faritowich Да не поддерживает, как и альтернативный HTML текст Intent.EXTRA_HTML_TEXT не работает нигде.

Comment: @faritowich Посмотрел исходники [FairEmail](https://github.com/M66B/FairEmail/blob/9c188ce73ee8579c398428229e1ecd7847c7a697/app/src/main/java/eu/faircode/email/ActivityCompose.java) там поддерживается все

Comment: Да уж. Спасибо!